# How can I fit my experimental curve using this equation using python?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

The equation is
$ Y = \left(a*\arctan\left(\frac{x \pm b}{b} * c\right)\right) + d x $

I tried fitting using `scipy.optimize` but could not include $\pm$
Here $ a , b, c, d$ are the parameters to be determined by fitting and $x , y$ are found using experiments i.e., M-H loop. This equation when applied should give hysteresis loop.

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
    import numpy as np 
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    def equation(x,a,b,c,d):
        x = np.array(x, dtype = float)
        a = float(a)
        b = float(b)
        c = float(c)
        d = float(d)
   
        e1 = a*np.arctan(((x + b)/b)*c) + d*x
        
        return e1
    
    data = [] #my experimental data
    x = [float(row[0]) for row in data]
    y = [float(row[1]) for row in data]
    initial_guesses = [] #taken correctly 

    params, covariance = curve_fit(equation, x, y, p0 = initial_guesses)


    parameter_errors = np.sqrt(np.diag(covariance))

    plt.scatter(x,y, label = ' Experimental Data')
    plt.plot(x, equation(x, *params), 'r', label = 'Fit')
    plt.legend()
```

I am not getting the required hysteresis loop may be because $\pm $ is not included.

Comment: The parameters are not independent. This could cause non-convergence of the regression calculus. Why two parameters $d$ and $h$ instead of only one as a unique coefficient of $x$ ?

Comment: $ Y = \left(a*\arctan\left(\frac{x \pm b}{b} * c\right)\right) + d x $ how can this be fitted rather

Comment: Due to the $\pm$, your equation defines a loop, not a curve, so a curve-fitting algorithm won't work. You could split this into two curves, one in each direction, and estimate each independently.

Comment: @Dipankar Pokhrel : You should joint to the question an example of data (numerical not graphical). Without data one cannot reproduce what you did and check.